# Make mesh follow other meshes movement like fluid/jelly

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am creating sort of a mechanical joint (not the weed one ;P) in blender with 4 components and I wanted one of the components to follow the sort of frames of the joint when I move it. The build can be seen in the picture.

(Maybe) important to know:
The both frames above and below are only extrudes circles, so when go to net view with Z I only see few circles. 
Second the jellyish part fits exactly inside the two frames and when I do it as in the picture I have first the problem of mesh inside mesh and second the jellyish mesh is going a bit through the frame: The joint will only be able to move up to this angle but on every side. 
I hope somebody has a good idea for this and can help. :)
Thanks for the attention.[image]

Comment: Could you specify what kind of answer you are expecting? I was thinking about a rig for an animation from the title, but I don't see any tags about it. Could you also better describe the needed movement and the behaviour of the jellish part? Only squeezed when compressed and stretched when put in traction?

Comment: Since I am pretty new to blender and didn't do anything in matter of rigging I didn't have it in mind so I didn't put it to the tags, sorry about that. I expect that when it comes to rigging any day that when I move this joint as seen in the middle, because that's simply the only way this joint can move, that the mesh which is around the sphere moving with it and not breaking through at as seen in the picture.

Comment: Start with a few simple rigging tutorials. Bones deform meshes in a way suitable for your example.